# How to create a text file in the internet that can be updated via python

Tags: python

So, I am just learning programming in python.

I wanted to create a basic text file and upload it somewhere, where I can edit the file content from python and push the update back to the url so that other people could view the updates.

Is this process too complicated for a beginner? To clarify, I'm not planning to buy a domain name or anything. I just need some medium to communicate online in the simplest form, be it basic html or use of a drop box etc.

**tldr:** I know how to open/save/create files from python and access urls, I need help in finding a platform to save the text file and a way to manipulate and update it via python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Writing to files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- [Uploading files with FTP](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2015/08/18/python-3-upload-files-over-ftp/)
- [Urllib2 for HTTP requests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)
- [Hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)

First of all, you may want to set-up a XAMPP (Windows) or LAMP (Linux) server. It's not hard, you only have to install a few pieces of software. That way you can make your own computer a server and access it by using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.

- [Install LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP - Linux)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)
- [Install XAMPP (Cross-platform, Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl - Windows/Cross-platform)](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows)

I listed all the things you needed, above.
First you of course have to learn how to create and write a file. After that file is created, you'll upload it to a server.
You can use several protocols for that, and Python has good supported libraries for each protocol (SSH/FTP). Ftplib is such a library which allows you to easily upload files using Python.

Maybe, you just want to edit the text file by sending a string to the server, instead of uploading the whole file each time you edit it. For that, you need to send a HTTP GET-request. This can be done by e.g using a library like Urllib2. However, with this method, you'll also need a few lines of PHP on your server to [take the GET-parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [put that content in a text-file.](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)

To check if a file has changed, you could make use of hashes.
Each file has an unique hash, by checking if the hashes of two files matches, you know it are two the same files.

Comment: thanks, this was helpful and i feel it is necessary for me to learn this. However, ill wait for an quicker hack (if it exists) while i look up all these new terms im not familiar with :)

Comment: @firelitte The point of Python is that it are all "quick hacks", Python is invented to make development quick. Hence why there is a library for everything you want to do. What in some languages take you like 100 lines of code, take you 15 in Python. So, you could do this very quick in Python; however, this all doesn't mean you don't have to learn Python. Take a cup of coffee, read the URLs I sent you, and when you're ready reading, you'll be able to do this all in less than a hour. We won't do the learning for you.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are looking for [SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)

Once Python has updated the file on your computer you can use SFTP to upload the updated file to your web server so that your viewer will see the new file.

Here are some examples of what you can do with SFTP:

http://www.tecmint.com/sftp-command-examples/

Comment: the question asks for a way to upload file *via python*.